# check if a user with specifc id is logged in or not laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

How do I check if a specific user is logged in or not?

```
Auth::check() or Auth::user()->id
```

will not work as I need to check the user with specific user id like I want to check if a user with `id = 53` is logged in or not then what Laravel auth function can I use

I have a middleware so would this be like Auth::guard('provider')->id?

Comment: `if (Auth::check() && Auth::id() == 53) { // Do something }`? You could probably also just use `Auth::user()->id` instead of `Auth::id()` since they do the same thing.

Comment: I have a middleware so would this be like Auth::guard('provider')->id?

Comment: Please update your question to include _all_ information (where you need to do this, what you've attempted etc).

Comment: it is giving me error ErrorException in UserController.php line 698:
Undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::$id

Comment: you want to check if the current user is user with `id == 53` or you want to figure out how to find out if any user on the entire site is logged in with the `id == 53`?

Comment: @lagbox I want to figure out how to find out if any user on the entire site is logged in with the id == 53 ...

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use the `database` session driver, which would also be storing the `user_id` with the session data. You could look for a record in the `sessions` table by `user_id` and based on the `last_activity` field roughly determine they are "logged in".

Comment: so can I call it with this Session::last_activity('53')

Comment: no, `Auth` and `Session` aren't going to help you as they are using the current request, you are actually trying to do stuff outside these systems. you will need to do this querying yourself

Comment: I am using database as session driver, but I have two auth controller, one is user and other is provider, auth user session is inserting correctly but provider session is not inserting, can you please tell where can I add the  code to insert provider login session as well